# Update category object from form through ajax call

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create index page for categories to display all categories. Each row has Category name and buttons to delete and edit category. When I click on edit button I want row to be changed to a form with text field with prepopulated name and button save. SO far I accomplished clicking edit button and displaying edit form inside the row. But when I click save button nothing happens. Like completely nothing. Console has no errors, network shows no calls made, server log shows no activity. I thought I add all necessary code to handle the call, but at this point I don't know where to look at. Can someone please advise? I use rails v 4.2.5.

Application.js

```
//this is for clicking edit and displaying Edit form inside the row
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
      $("[name='edits']").on('ajax:complete', function(event, data, status) {
        $(this).parent().parent().html(data.responseText)
      })
    })

    //this is to handle click on save button
    document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
      $('#edit-form').on('ajax:complete', function(event, data, status){
        $('#categories').html(data.responseText);
      })
    })
```

Category controller:

```
def edit
    render  partial: 'categories/edits'
  end

  def update
    if @category.update(category_params)
      flash[:success] = "Category #{@category.name} was saved successfully"
    else
      flash[:danger] = "There was an error please try again!"
    end
    render partial: 'categories/list'
  end
```

Edit form partial:

```
<div>
  <%= form_tag category_path, remote: true, method: :put, name: "edit-form" do %>
    <div class="form-group row text-center col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <%= text_field_tag :name, @category.name, 
                                  placeholder: "Category Name", autofocus: true,
                                  class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <%= button_tag(type: :submit, class: "btn btn-primary") do %>
          Save
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

In html I noticed that input field and button is outside the form. Can this be the reason of issue? Like that

```
<form></form>
<input>
<button></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I figured the problem was in putting form inside tr tag. Moving it in td seems to fix the issue.